# tkinter - loading gif until def has came out

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

when i start the process def loading(): has come out until print("hello world") and also without click button in def loading(): when i start the def loading(): it must be click button and use command with button but i dont wanna do like that lastly i just want to make when i start process def loading(): has come out first until print("hello world") without any click button or something clicking please help me

```
from PIL import Image


def hi():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("hello world")

    
def loading():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg='white')

    file="giphy.gif"

    info = Image.open(file)

    frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains

    # creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
    im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

    count = 0
    anim = None
    def animation(count):
        global anim
        im2 = im[count]

        gif_label.configure(image=im2)
        count += 2
        if count == frames:
            count = 0
        anim = root.after(100,lambda :animation(count))

    gif_label = tk.Label(root,image="",bg='white',)
    gif_label.pack()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want `hi()` to execute first?

Comment: `time.sleep(10)` will literally cause the entire application to sleep, which means it won't update the display or process any events of any time. There are countless questions on this site about delaying things. Do some research on the `after` method provided by tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows a way to do it. When the `def hi()` function executes and print the message, it now also sets a global flag variable which the function doing the animation checks periodically. When the value of the flag has changed, it causes the animation to cease.

```
from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk

stop = False  # Global flag.

def hi():
    global stop
    print("hello world")
    stop = True

def loading(filename):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg='white')

    info = Image.open(filename)
    frames = info.n_frames  # gives total number of frames that gif contains

    # creating list of PhotoImage objects for each frames
    im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=filename, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

    count = 0
    def animation(count):
        frame = im[count]
        gif_label.configure(image=frame)
        count = (count+1) % frames
        if not stop:
            root.after(200, lambda: animation(count))

    btn = tk.Button(text="Start", command=lambda: animation(count))
    btn.pack()

    gif_label = tk.Label(root, image="", bg='white',)
    gif_label.pack()

    root.after(5000, hi)  # Call hi() in 5 seconds.

    root.mainloop()


loading("small_globe.gif")
```

Comment: can i use this code without "start" button?

Comment: Yes, but there won't be any animation — _something_ has to call `animation(count)` to start it. Since you have made it a local nested function, this has to occur within the context of the `loading()` function.